# AngularJs Phone book effect (letters in ng-repeat)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Hi i need to paste letters between names in sorted objects array

```js
$scope.names = [
{name: Anna}
{name: Angelina}
{name: Ivan}
{name: Michael}
{name: Marina}
]
```

```html
<div ng-repeat="user in names">

<div>{{user.name}}</div>
  
</div>
```

And result should be:

A
Anna
Angelina

I
Ivan

M
Michael
Marina

I have no idea how to insert breaking First letter

Comment: you are going to have to build a grouping filter.  There are quite a few examples if you search around, but it's a bit much to write a working solution as an answer here.

Comment: What about making `names` an object with keys being alphabets and value being an array containing names starting with those alphabets? You can then just iterate over it an print the keys and repeat the values

Comment: Good point, thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Custom Filter like below,

```
$scope.myCustomFilterA = function(player) {
        return player.name.substring(0,1).match(/A/gi) && $scope.otherCondition;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/jV6DK/144/)**

Comment: Hm...and i shoul write the same filter for  27th letter of the English alphabet ??

Comment: then you should use the alphabet as a parameter in filter. can you mark as answer if it has helpped